# How to update gtk-3.4 themes to the new gtk-3.6

Tags: gnome, updates, themes, gtk, gtk3

Is it too complicated to achieve? if it's not could you tell me how, please. I have some basic knowledge about gtk and css. Also, is this going to continue happening each time gnome releases a new version?

Comment: I'd like to know this too especially the backward compatibility part.

Comment: This is an interesting read on the problem: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=687752

Answer (score 1):

For this (**with custom WARNINGs !**) you need add Gnome Testing PPA and update your system:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ricotz/testing
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: I don't think this answers the question — I think it's about upgrading an actual theme that the asker is authoring, not Gnome itself.